# Zend_Loader_Autoloader vs. Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader

Tags: php, class, zend-framework

What is the difference with these three classes? They all seem to have similar function. Can someone explain this to me clearly and which ones are used by Zend_Application automatically?

```
Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource
Zend_Loader_Autoloader
```

Comment: Did you read their respective descriptions in the [ZF reference guide](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/reference.html)? Can you please point out more precisely what is unclear to you about them?

Comment: Yes, I did. All the Zend specific jargon is a little difficult to keep up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blatantly copied over from the reference guide. Please point any trouble you have understanding their concepts, so we can provide additional explanation.

[Zend_Loader_Autoloader](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)

> Zend_Loader_Autoloader introduces a comprehensive autoloading solution for Zend Framework. It has been designed with several goals in mind:
>
> - Provide a true namespace autoloader. (Previous incarnations intercepted all userland namespaces.)
> - Allow registering arbitrary callbacks as autoloaders, and manage them as a stack. (At the time of this writing, this overcomes some issues with spl_autoload, which does not allow re-registering a callback that utilizes an instance method.)
> - Allow optimistic matching of namespaces to provide faster class resolution.

[Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html)

> Resource autoloaders are intended to manage namespaced library code that follow Zend Framework coding standard guidelines, but which do not have a 1:1 mapping between the class name and the directory structure. Their primary purpose is to facilitate autoloading application resource code, such as application-specific models, forms, and ACLs.
>
> Resource autoloaders register with the autoloader on instantiation, with the namespace to which they are associated. This allows you to easily namespace code in specific directories, and still reap the benefits of autoloading.

[Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module)

> Zend Framework ships with a concrete implementation of Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource that contains resource type mappings that cover the default recommended directory structure for Zend Framework MVC applications.

Comment: OK so, Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader is for loading *your* application's classes. Zend_Loader_Autoloader is for loading Zend Framework classes. Correct??? Are there any other similar classes?

Comment: @sims No. Module loads stuff in ZF Modules. You can group related parts of your application into Modules inside your application folder and this autoloader will load them. The Resource Autoloader loads everything that doesnt match the regular ZF naming conventions of My_Zend_Class_Name to My/Zend/Class/Name.php and the Zend_Autoloader is the general autoloader.

Comment: So Zend_Autoloader takes care of loading the standard ZF classes? If I follow the path underscore (My_Zend_Class_Name to My/Zend/Class) convention, I should not have to use anything special then? Just (includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library") in my .ini perhaps?

Comment: @sims almost. You have to tell it to load "My", even when following the convention. See http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html#zend.loader.autoloader.usage

Comment: Ah yes, OK cool. Thanks for that! I think it's getting clearer. I will read more as well.

Comment: @sims from my experience with ZF, you will rarely make contact with the autoloaders if you follow ZF conventions and do the few necessary configurations correctly.

Comment: I started using ZF quite a bit before the "conventions" were established. So in a way, I'm more behind than a new comer.